# How to validate the length of nested tuple passed to a function?

Tags: python, list, tuples, args

I am building a function that accepts the list of tuples. For example:

```
my_list = [
     ("str1", 1, 11),
     ("str2", 2, 22), 
     ("str3", 3, 33),
     ("str4", 4, 44)
]
```

I want to create a function with definition such that it will ONLY accept the parameters with the size of each nested element as "3". How can I define my function to accept list only of my desired nested length?

Here is the sample code snippet of what I am trying to achieve *(I know it is syntactically incorrect)*:

```
def newattr_ratio(data, *(name,idx,idy)):

    for name,idx,idy in *(name,idx,idy):
        data[name]= data[data.columns[idx]]/data[data[columns[idy]]]
```

How can I create a function with such parameter definition?

Comment: your function defintion should be `def newattr_ratio(data, *args)`. Then loop it as `for name,idx,idy in args`:

Comment: *"what is after the * is just a name, right?"* Not sure what you mean

Comment: Pass a tuple of tuples?

Comment: Why do you need to define *"the format of the argument"*?

Comment: Replace `*(name,idx,idy)` with `positions` and it'll work.

Comment: @PeterWood  after the *name , name is just a word it can not represent a type of a variable

Comment: @PeterWood i dont need to define type i could deal with it later but is there a way to define the length of each tuple argument past to the fucntion to be 3 exactly?

Comment: @cdarke no a series of tuple 1, 2, or more but all of the same format

Comment: What do you mean by *series* of tuples? It looks like a tuple of tuples to me.  And no, you cannot force the number of elements at the argument definition line, you will have to code the check yourself - its not a big deal to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not restrict that during the declaration of your functional parameter. However you may **create a custom decorator to check for the length of your nested tuples** as:

```
from functools import wraps

def check_params(nestedsize=None):
    def _check_params(func):
        def _decorator(data, *args ):
            if nestedsize and all(len(arg)==nestedsize for arg in args):
                return func(data, *args)
            else:
                raise Exception("Invalid args passed with the function call")
        return wraps(func)(_decorator)
    return _check_params
```

*Above decorator takes the optional parameter `nestedsize` to check the size of your nested tuples.*

Now, **for passing the unpacked version of lists to your function**, your function definition should be:

```
@check_params(nestedsize=3)    # <-- added decorator here, with nested size as "3"
def newattr_ratio(data, *args):  # <-- note the asterisk sign here
    for name, idx, idy in args:
        print("{} - {} - {}".format(name, idx, idy))
```

Sample Run:

```
# Correct input
>>> my_list = [("a", 1, 11), ("b", 2, 22), ("c", 3, 33)]

#                     v asterisk again to unpack the list
>>> newattr_ratio([], *my_list)
a - 1 - 11
b - 2 - 22
c - 3 - 33

# Incorrect input, raising custom exception
>>> my_list = [("a", 1, 11, "wrong_data"), ("b", 2, 22), ("c", 3, 33)]

>>> newattr_ratio([], *my_list)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in _decorator
Exception: Invalid args passed with the function call
```

If you **do NOT want to unpack the list and pass it as it is**, then your function should be:

```
@check_params(nestedsize=3) 
def newattr_ratio(data, args):  # <-- No asterisk here
    for name, idx, idy in args:
        print("{} - {} - {}".format(name, idx, idy))
        # ... whatever your logic is
```

Sample run *(same result as above, only difference is in function call)*:

```
# correct input
>>> my_list = [("a", 1, 11), ("b", 2, 22), ("c", 3, 33)]
>>> newattr_ratio([], my_list)   # <-- No asterisk here
a - 1 - 11
b - 2 - 22
c - 3 - 33

# Incorrect input, raising custom exception
>>> my_list = [("a", 1, 11, "wrong_data"), ("b", 2, 22), ("c", 3, 33)]

>>> newattr_ratio([], my_list)   # <-- No asterisk here
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in _decorator
Exception: Invalid args passed with the function call
```

---

However if you won't use the decorator, anyway your for loop will raise the exception as `ValueError: too many values to unpack`. So you may skip the decorator if you are fine without custom exception

For example:

```
#                               v extra value here
>>> my_list = [("a", 1, 11, "wrong_data"), ("b", 2, 22), ("c", 3, 33)]

>>> newattr_ratio([], my_list)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in newattr_ratio
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: @Tummomoxie edited the answer with decorator based approach. You might be interested in taking a look at it

Comment: That was very helpful. Thanks for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have it a bit wrong. The format to handle the variable amount of parameters is "def newattr_ratio(data, *t_uple)". The "*t_uple" indicates that it will be a variable amount of parameters. An example is below:

```
def add (*arg):
    sum = 0
    for t_uple in arg:
        for x in t_uple:
            sum = sum +x
    return sum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arg_1 = (1, 2, 3)
    arg_2 = (5, 6, 7)
sum = add(arg_1,arg_2)
print(sum)
```

Comment: Yes that is what I mean by saying that whatever is after asterix is just a name (could be *arg, *aaarg, or anything else). That's why I didn't know how to express it. Thank's for help.

Answer (score -1):

Have the function accept a list of tuples as an argument

```
def newattr_ratio(data, myListOfTuples):
    for myTuple in myListOfTuples:
        data[myTuple[0]]= data[data.columns[myTuple[1]]/data[data[columns[myTuple[2]]]
```

Comment: That would work, but it doesn't specify the exact size of the tuple. Can I even specify this in the function definition, or do I have write try catch to throw exceptions when the passed tuple is not of correct dimensions?

Comment: Yeah you can do that as a hack to make it work, though I was under the impression that your data in the tuple was well-defined and not variant between calls.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was downvoted so much, it's a solution. Can someone that downvoted it explain?